# How to use np.where to find the index value of a certain element within an array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Here is my sample data:

```
# sample data
xdata = [3.33172, 3.33348, 3.33525, 3.33702, 3.33878, 3.34055, 3.34232, 
3.34408, 3.34585, 3.34762, 3.34938, 3.35115, 3.35292 , 3.35468, 3.35645, 
3.35822, 3.35998, 3.36175, 3.36352, 3.36529, 3.36705, 3.36882] 
ydata = [-0.00437834, -0.00486735, -0.0118371, -0.00582171, 0.00339488, 
-0.000369502, -0.000898799, -0.00797662, -0.00853566, -0.0123596, 
-0.0162318, -0.0103355, -0.00445416, 0.00137920, -0.00251916, -0.00968244, 
0.00260652, 0.00841350, 0.00445556, 0.00373271, 0.00621243, 0.00220983]
```

How could I use np.where to find the index value of 3.35115, for example?

Comment: Beware that equality tests with floats sometimes give unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first turn your data into a `numpy` array so you can check where it is `==` to your target value:

```
>>> np.where(np.array(xdata) == 3.35115)
# (array([11]),)
```

This says that index 11 of `xdata` is 3.35115.